CG limits of Piper Pawnee?
In looking at a Piper Pawnee I found in the cockpit most of the expected documents, including a POH and a signed-by-A&P weight and balance sheet for that particular aircraft. The POH lists the max gross as 2900 lb, but I couldn't find anything documenting CG limits. Now, to be fair, this is a single seat, over the wing, it has a small baggage shelf behind the pilot's head, and the 38 gallon fuel tank. The agricultural spray hopper is removed, so  it's really hard to imagine that any possible loading would push it out of CG limit. That said, it seems to me that it's not entirely inconceivable that an FAA inspector might demand that I prove I'm in limits.
Does anyone have any information, ideally with a credible source, on what the limits are? Or, perhaps, an idea of where I could find such information? I suppose perhaps it's part of a type certificate, but I don't know how I'd find a copy of that?
Thanks for any suggestions/info!

The W&B report and POH should have all the data you need. It's pretty strange for the W&B sheet not to have the CG limits included.

Maybe they should, and I would agree that the POH suggests the W/B sheet for the airplane ought to have in this case, but for this airplane they don't (unless, perhaps, it's really well hidden in the POH). See page 18 in this (which is not the exact M/M I'm looking at, but this appears to be extremely similar POH, just a bit newer: https://www.soarccsc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CCSC-Pawnee-D-POH.pdf

The POH just refers to the sheet.  And there you are.  If the data isn't on the airplane's W&B report, you have a problem.  I tow gliders in a Pawnee and I've never checked it lol.

Yeah, embarrassing, isn't it. I've been flying Pawnees for 20 years, and this is the first time I've noticed. And that because locals are whining about noise, trying to close the airport, and complaining to the FAA that we're "not doing things right", so we're expecting, and preparing for, ramp checks.

Wow. If your sheet has the empty weights, moments and CG, maybe write to Piper for the W&B load chart?

Well, that's a thought. I just hoped maybe someone here might actually know the limits, but that's not looking promising so far.
